# Redraw Graph on Print Preview - Is Not a Function (Nested Vue Component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know I'm not accessing this function correct by the error, but I'm not sure how to debug this and determine the correct approach. Guidance is appreciated.

`PerformanceDonut.vue` is a component in `Page.vue`

`PerformanceDonut.vue`:

```
// ...
methods: {
    drawGraph() {
        this.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(this.chartName, this.chartOptions);
        this.chart.render();
         console.log('Donut drawn')
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.drawGraph();
    // The function executes here

    // Redraw graph on print preview
    window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            this.drawGraph();
            // Error here
        }
    });
}
```

Console Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.drawGraph is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an arrow function in order to work `this` as reference of Vue component:

```js
window.matchMedia('print').addListener( mql => {
    if (mql.matches) {
        this.drawGraph();
    }
});
```

Comment: "In regular functions the this keyword represented the object that called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button or whatever. With arrow functions the this keyword always represents the object that defined the arrow function." Thank you! Explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

Answer (score 1):

Assign `this` to a global variable called `vm` and then access it in the callback since the execution context  is changed in the callback:

```
   mounted() {
            this.drawGraph();
            // The function executes here

            let vm=this;
            window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(mql) {
                if (mql.matches) {
                    vm.drawGraph();

                }
            });
```